# How do I define the function signature for my PyGame project?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to determine the positional arguments (I think thats what they are called) for this function `fireshell()`.

I have tried combinations of `self` and the variables `elapsedTime`, `pos.x`, and `pos.y` without success. I am trying to determine what arguments to pass in both the call and in the definition.

I am new to programming so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

```
 if event.type == pg.KEYUP:

       if event.key == pg.K_0:
                self.endTime = time.time()
                self.end = timer()
                self.E = pg.time.get_ticks()
                self.elapsedTime = self.endTime - self.startTime
                print("ENDING", self.endTime, self.startTime)
                print("elapsed time", (self.endTime - self.startTime))
                print (self.start, self.end, "difference", (self.end - self.start))
                print ( "E", self.E, "S", self.S)
                print("elapsed time", self.elapsedTime)
                self.player.fireshell( ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

## me with fireshell

```
def fireshell(?, ?, ?, ?):
    fire = True
    print("fire", self.pos.x, self.pos.y)
    fireX = int(self.pos.x) 
    fireY = int(self.pos.y) - 30  


    while fire:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                quit()
        pg.draw.circle(self.screen, RED, (fireX, fireY), 5)

        fireX -= (12 - elapsedTime)*2
        print(elapsedTime)
        print(fireX)
        pg.display.update()
        self.clock.tick(20)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to pass variables to a function?

Comment: I guess so. I am confused on when to pass "self" and "elaspedTime". Neither seem to work. I guess I am missing some key logic.

Comment: If you want to pass `self.elapsedTime` to `fireshell`, do it like this: `self.player.fireshell(self.elapsedTime)`

Comment: @MattMacy Hey man, it sounds like you're just learning how this works. It sounds like following a good tutorial on writing functions is what you need. When I was starting out, I followed https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm to see how they worked. We can't help you with your function because it's entirely up to you. You get to determine what you need to pass in, because you wrote what the function did.

Comment: I believe the call is now working but I can't put self.fireshell in the definition. What would I put there? I would like to get pos.x and pos.y into the function as well.

Comment: You can only put variable names in the definition. `self.fireshell` is an attribute of whatever class `self` is. You could do it like `def fireshell(self, pos_x, pos_y)` instead. I can't help you further. I strongly recommend you post the question somewhere else more suited for beginners. /r/learnpython is a great place for that.

Comment: You always need to pass all the arguments unless they have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are actually trying to pass in to the function. Ignoring variables for a second, what are you trying to accomplish with this function? It looks like you are trying to fire the projectile. Right now the self.pos.x and self.pos.y I assume are the position of whatever you have that is doing the firing of the projectile (a tank maybe? or whatever is firing the projectile). So I would think that this would be the starting point of the projectile's path. The lines

```
fireX = int(self.pos.x) 
fireY = int(self.pos.y) - 30
```

would b setting the start point for the projectile (same x as the tank's x, and 30 pixels above the tank's y, which sounds like a pretty standard start point). Then, after that you have your fire loop, which is just moving the projectile along its path. The problem that I see with the loop is that that loop is infinite. You initialize the fire variable to true

```
fire = True
```

but you never make that false, so the "while fire" loop will infinitely loop. You need to make a condition to where the loop ends, which is up to you. You just need to decide when you want the tank projectile's path end, and when this happens, set fire to false, and the loop will end, continuing your basic game functions.

As to what you need to pass in. From what I can see of it looks like you are using an object to store your data (from how you used self.pos.x), so what I would do is just put the fireshell function inside of this class, and then you do not need to pass anything to the function, you can just use self.pos.x, self.pox.y, and self.elapsed time within the function itself, and since the function would be a member of the same class as those variables, there should be no access conflicts or errors.

Comment: Excuse me, I see what you are saying up to the point of making a class.